# Não consigo listar uma tabela em php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Não consigo listar uma simples tabela em php... Não vejo o que há de mal com o código, quando executo este código php apenas me mostra uma página em branco... O que estou a fazer de mal?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Listar Alunos</alunos>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

     //Conecta ao servidor e escolhe a base de dados
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
     mysql_select_db("login");

     $query = "SELECT * FROM alunos";


     if ($resposta = mysql_query($query)){
         echo
         '
         <table align = "left" cellspacing = "5" cellpadding = "8">
         <tr><th align = "left"><b>Primeiro Nome</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Último Nome</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Email</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Rua</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Cidade</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Telemóvel</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Data de Nascimento</b></th>
         <th align = "left"><b>Sexo</b></th><tr>
         ';

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resposta)){
             echo '<tr><td align = "left">' .
             $row['primeiro_nome'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['ultimo_nome'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['email'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['rua'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['cidade'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['telemovel'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['data_aniversario'] . '</td><td align = "left">' .
             $row['sexo'] . '</td>' ;

             echo '</tr>';
         }
         echo '</table>';

         } else{
            echo "Não foi possível listar os alunos. ".mysql_error();
         }

    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: mysql esta obsoleto, utilize mysqli ou pdo

Comment: é para um projeto da escola... Visto que não posso mexer nas máquinas de lá, infelizmente tenho de usar na versão de php 5... Acha que o problema pode ser dai?

Comment: Você esta testando localmente, ou no servidor da escola?

Comment: Esse arquivo tem que extensão?

Comment: localmente, com o xampp

Comment: chama-se listar.php

Comment: Compartilha esse códgio listar.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem bastante coisa errada nesse seu código meu amigo, um deles é lá no seu `<title>`:

```
<title>Listar Alunos</alunos>
```

Você está fechando a tag `<title>` com `</alunos>`, então tudo que você faz depois disso, vai ficar no seu título. Pode colocar o mouse em cima da sua aba e ver que toda a sua sintaxe está ali. Mude para:

```
<title>Listar Alunos</title>
```

E outra, o mysql está obsoleto, mude para o mysqli, é mais fácil você adaptar a ele do que para o PDO.

Posso lhe ajudar a migrar seu código para o mysqli (adicione um i) e você cria um arquivo **conexao.php** e antes do seu `$resposta = mysql_query($query)` você irá colocar:

```
$resposta = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
```

E outra, não use um **array** aqui:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($resposta)
```

Use um **assoc**:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resposta)
```

De resto acho que não muda muito a não ser adicionar um **i** no seu *mysql*.

Segue um arquivo **conexao.php**:

```
<?php
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "123";
  $dbname = "teste";

  //Criar Conexão
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

?>
```

E na sua página *index.php*, logo após você abrir a tag **PHP**, coloque:

```
include_once("conexao.php")
```

E então consegue colocar o `$conn` no **mysqli_query**.

Comment: Obrigado! Apenas foi preciso mudar o código do título e funcionou tudo...

Comment: Às vezes são mesmo estúpidas as coisas que nos passam xd

Comment: Por nada amigo, e sim, as vezes passam coisas tão simples que não damos muita bola para elas, apenas focamos na parte mais difícil do código pois é a primeira coisa que um programador pensa quando algo não está funcionando no código. Por isso aconselho um bom editor de códigos, pois alguns indicam onde fecha tal tag e assim facilita a evitar esses errinhos bobos kk